# Python is not recognized in the VSC integrated terminal

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-python

### Environment data

- VS Code version: 1.47.3
- Extension version (available under the Extensions sidebar): XXX
- OS and version: Windows Server 2019
- Python version (& distribution if applicable, e.g. Anaconda): Python 3.7.8 and Python 3.8.4 (downloaded from Python.org)
- Type of virtual environment used (N/A | venv | virtualenv | conda | ...): NA
- Relevant/affected Python packages and their versions:
- Relevant/affected Python-related VS Code extensions and their versions: Python 2020.7.96456  and Shell launcher 0.4.1
- Value of the `python.languageServer` setting: None

### Expected behaviour

When I select the Python Interpreter version, I expect to get the selected version in the VSC integrated terminal.

### Actual behaviour

When I type Python in the integrated terminal, the command is not recognized.
In my user settings, I'm setting the PATH environment variable (I removed the path for the python directory here). Also I'm excluding myself from the A/B pythonPath testing.

### Steps to reproduce:

[image: Python-Interpreter]

### Logs

Output from Python output channel

```
> conda --version
> pyenv root
> python3.7 c:\Users\el.mehdi.el.aouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python3.6 c:\Users\el.mehdi.el.aouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python3 c:\Users\el.mehdi.el.aouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python2 c:\Users\el.mehdi.el.aouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python c:\Users\el.mehdi.el.aouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> py -3.7 c:\Users\el.mehdi.el.aouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> py -3.6 c:\Users\el.mehdi.el.aouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> py -3 c:\Users\el.mehdi.el.aouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> py -2 c:\Users\el.mehdi.el.aouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe c:\Users\el.mehdi.el.aouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> ~\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe info --json
Starting Pylance language server.
Python interpreter path: ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
Error 2020-08-06 14:59:13: Attempted to download with skipDownload true.
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe c:\Users\el.mehdi.el.aouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import jupyter"
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe c:\Users\el.mehdi.el.aouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import jupyter"
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe c:\Users\el.mehdi.el.aouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import notebook"
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe c:\Users\el.mehdi.el.aouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import notebook"
Error 2020-08-06 14:59:16: Detection of Python Interpreter for Command py and args -2 failed as file Python 2 not found!

 -3.8-64
 -3.7-64 does not exist
Error 2020-08-06 14:59:16: Detection of Python Interpreter for Command py and args -3.6 failed as file Python 3.6 not found!

 -3.8-64
 -3.7-64 does not exist
> ~\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe info --json
> ~\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe env list
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe c:\Users\el.mehdi.el.aouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py pip --version
Python interpreter path: ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe c:\Users\el.mehdi.el.aouni\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py pip --version
Editor support is inactive since language server is set to None.
Python interpreter path: ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
```

Comment: This is not a place to report product issues. The integrated terminal is not different from another terminal you open, so it is not surprising that it resolves Python path based on its own logic.

Comment: I've already posted on the github issue page and waiting for the answer. I was just wondering if someone has the same problem. Normally the INTEGRATED terminal kind of add the selected Python interperter to the PATH so that it would be recognized.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There is an explanation here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13327